# Can I use a formatted address in Google Places API call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am hoping to provide a specific function in my app. I want to be able to enter an address, or use an address stored in a database e.g. "119 Harley Street, London" or "119 Harley Street" (this is just a random address to illustrate my requirements taken from the Google Places 'vicinity' field relating to a business called "The London Clinic Eye Centre").

Based on the address entered, I would like to be able to identify the Business Name at this address, if there is one, so the 'name' field in the Places JSON result, and also identify if there are any recent reviews by customers, with Date/Time and the review itself, photos etc.

Is this at all possible, or am I looking for something that isn't possible? I have experience of using other Google APIs (Geolocation & JS) but this is a new one to me, and can't see any way of achieving this from the documentation - I hope I am missing something.

Can anyone help? An alternative way of achieving what I need would also be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are pretty much describing the Places API.  Have you seen this example? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: hi dana, thanks for response....had a look, so how do I get the results into a JSON dataset...I reckon I need the 'Place ID' in the results as well as the name, which will then allow me to do a Places Detail search for reviews

Comment: does this line...var places = searchBox.getPlaces();...return an array of places objects? if so, that's the missing link in my head, simple after that.

Comment: ok, so your example has helped me to a point...I can do what I need successfully when the autocomplete only offers 1 business but some addresses have multiple businesses e.g. 119 Harley Street, London has 4, how do I get the Place ID, name etc. of these 4 into an array. So when I type 119 Harley Street, London into the autocomplete box, 4 business names appear....this is what I will need access to, all 4 or whatever the number may be 1...n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like the *At this location* in Google Maps ([example](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/Bahnhofstrasse+30,+8001+Z%C3%BCrich/@47.3705904,8.5380751,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47900a00dd53b38d:0xe82ca251c20bc962!8m2!3d47.3705904!4d8.5391694?hl=en)):

[image]

This is not exactly available in the same way in the Places API, but I think you can use [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) to get pretty close:

1. Use Places Autocomplete (or Geocoding) to obtain the latlng for an address (or business, it doesn't matter).
2. Use Places Nearby Search to find all establishments at that location, by querying with that latlng as `location`, no `keyword`, and `rankby=distance`
3. Keep only the closest results (first few) and/or (maybe) filter by their address.

Example Nearby Search request for "Bahnhofstrasse 30 Zurich", which geocodes to 47.3705904,8.5391694:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=47.3705904,8.5391694&rankby=distance&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Results (name, vicinity):

1. Griederbar, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
2. Coiffure Valentino, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
3. Grieder G.Point, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
4. Shanty Beauty Design, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
5. Louis Vuitton, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
6. Brunschwig & Cie Sa, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
7. Clariden Leu, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
8. Gen Del Sa, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
9. Abegg & Co AG, Zürich, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
10. Wohlfahrtsfonds der Clariden Leu AG, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
11. Uhren shop Zürich Jaeger-LeCoultre, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
12. TOD'S Boutique, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
13. Audemars Piguet, Boutique Zurich, Bahnhofstrasse **32**, Zürich
14. Grieder, Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich
15. ─ 20. no more results at Bahnhofstrasse 30, Zürich

Comment: miguev, this does look like what I need. I was aware of rankby but never even thought about using it in this way, or even to use lat,lng in the search in this way - like it!...and the good thing is I actually have the lat,lng along with addresses to be searched in my database so can automate that part...will report back once I have tested

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snippet straight from Google that show you how to use the "prediction" API to get a list of suggested places:

```js
function initCallback() {
    var getDetailsCallback = function(place, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            alert(status);
            return;
        }
     // write details of place to console
        console.log('Place');
        console.log(place);
    };
    var getQueryPredictionsCallback = function(predictions, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            alert(status);
            return;
        }
        // write predictions to the console
        console.log('Predictions');
        console.log(predictions);

        // get details of each prediction
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
        var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
            placesService.getDetails({ placeId: prediction.place_id }, getDetailsCallback);  
        });
    };

    var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    autocompleteService.getQueryPredictions({ input: '119 Harley Street' }, getQueryPredictionsCallback);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&callback=initCallback" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response...I have just been playing about with this getQueryPredictions() & getPlacePredictions() but it doesn't give me all I need. If I type 119 Harley Street, London into an autocomplete input, you will see 4 business addresses appearing, I need these..the Places and Query predictions just give me Place Predictions which will just match or be similar to the address entered. Within the example address are 4 registered businesses each with a Place ID...these appear when the address is entered into an autocomplete input and so I assume you can get to them, but how?

Comment: The 1st result in your JSON relates to the first of the 4 businesses linked to this London address, but what about the other 3?

Comment: You may have to lookup the details of each place individually... If you notice each prediction has a `place_id` which can be fed to a place details service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details - There also appears to be a text search, but it behaves quite differently than the predictions api.

Comment: @nelly2000 - please see my updated answer where I take the results from the predictions api and send to the details api.

Comment: thanks again dana, just getting back online now...let me have a go at this and miguev's response and will report back